# googlemaps.exceptions.TransportError while calculating Distance Matrix

Tags: python-2.7, google-maps, google-api

Problem (with formatting):

```
TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='maps.googleapis.com', port=443):
  Max retries exceeded with url: /maps/api/distancematrix/json?destinations=17.445134%2C78.349222&mode=walking&origins=17.44882%2C78.344386&key=AIzaSyD9JkQXx1V6_Z9XUUcIXsUlYHpeCst3AcI 
  (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, u'[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:726)'),))
```

with this code:

```
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key = 'XYZ') 

query = "SELECT * FROM ridedetails WHERE (sourcecity LIKE '%" + City + "%' and sourcepincode = '"+ pincode +"') and ridetime = '" + rideTime + "'"
df = pd.read_sql(query, g.db)
distancelist = []
for index in range(len(df)):
  if session['userid'] == df.iloc[[index]]['userid'].iloc[0]:
    continue
  LatOrigin = df.iloc[[index]]['sourcelat'] 
  LongOrigin = df.iloc[[index]]['sourcelong']
  origins = (LatOrigin,LongOrigin)
  userorigin = (sourceLat, sourceLong)
  result = gmaps.distance_matrix(origins, userorigin, mode='walking')["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["distance"]["value"]
  distancelist.append(result)
  print(distancelist) 
  return distancelist
```

I want to calculate distance from one person to another person using Lat /Long of people.